# How to bind an NSTableView to multiple core data entity types

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data

I'm writing an application to help diabetics manage their condition. Information that is tracked includes blood sugar results, nutrition, exercise, and medication information.
In similar applications these entries are all presented in a single table view even though each type of entry has different fields.  This data is manually tracked by many diabetics in a logbook, and I'm looking to keep that paradigm.

Each entry has some common information (timestamp, category, and notes) as well as information specific to each entry type.  For instance, meal entries would have detailed nutrition information (carb counts, fiber, fat, etc), medication entries would indicate which medication and dosage, etc.

I've considered two different approaches but I'm getting stuck at both a conceptual level and a technical level when attempting to implement either.  The first approach was to create an abstract entity to contain all the common fields and then create entities for each log entry type (meals, meds, bg, etc.) that are parented to the abstract entity.  I had this all modeled out but couldn't quite figure out how to bind these items to an array controller to have them show up in a single table view.

The second approach is to have one entity that contains the common fields, and then model the specific entry types as separate entities that have a relationship back to the common record (sort of like a decorator pattern).  This was somewhat easier to build the UI for (at least for the common field entity), but I come to the same problem when wanting to bind the specific data entities.

Of course the easiest approach is to just throw all the fields from each different entry type into one entity but that goes against all my sensibilities.  And it seems I would still run into a similar problem when I go to bind things to the table view.

My end goal is to provide an interface to the user that shows each entry in chronological order in a unified interface instead of having to keep a separate list of each entry type. I'm fine with adding code where needed, but I'd like to use the bindings as much as possible.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get bogged down with entity inheritance. You shouldn't use it save duplicate attributes like you would with classes. It's major use is allow different entities to be in the same relationship. Also, entity inheritance and class inheritance don't have to overlap. You can have a class inheritance hierarchy without an entity inheritance hierarchy.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you really need but here's some generic advice: You shouldn't create your data model based on the needs of the UI. The data model is really a simulation of the real-world objects, events or conditions that your app deals with. You should create your data model first and foremost to accurately simulate the data. Ideally, you should create a data model that could be used with any UI e.g. command-line, GUI, web page etc.

Once your model is accurately setup, then whipping up the UI is usually easy.